# NLP work related to distinguishing scenes in a story

Tags: nlp

Say I have a story or novel with multiple scenes. Are there any NLP work/techniques that allow me to know when the author switches from one scene to another? Searching things like "context", "scene" in google does not yield good results.

Assume that I do not have a list of characters' names and there may be nameless NPCs.